# What regular expression can I use to find in an HTML document tables that only contain one row?

Tags: html, regex, pcre

I'm searching through HTML documents and trying to find tables that only contain a single row.  What regex can I use to do this?  I've tried negative lookahead and can isolate a single row, but I don't see how to ensure that there's only a single `<tr></tr>` between `<table></table>` tags.

Here's the regex I'm working with now:

```
<table[\W].*?<tr[\W].*?<\/tr>.*(?!.*<tr[\W])<\/table>
```

This should NOT match the regex:

```
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

This SHOULD match the regex:

```
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [Don't try to parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  Use a specialized HTML-aware parsing tool, like [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:  `<table>(?>[^<]++|<(?!\/tr>))*<\/tr>(?>[^<]++|<(?!\/tr>))<\/table>`

It is looking for only one instance of `</tr>` between `<table>` and `</table>`.

Details about it can be found here: [Negative Lookaround Regex - Only one occurrence - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374967/negative-lookaround-regex-only-one-occurrence-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could go for an approach with `DOMDocument` and `xpath` functions (namely `count()`). Assuming, you're using `PHP` (your question is tagged with `PCRE`):

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<html>
<head/>
<body>
    <table id="two_rows">
        <tr><td>One column</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Another column</td></tr>
    </table>

    <table id="one_row">
        <tr><td>One column</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tables = $xpath->query("//table[count(tr) = 1]");
print_r($tables);
?>
```

---

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/UsQ5LG).

Comment: Why would you assume PHP? PCRE is a C library ;)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Just my *spidey sense* :) Who is trying to analyze `HTML` in `C`nowadays, anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Using `.match()` you can count the <tr>.

Try this:
`str.match( /<tr.*?<\/tr>/g ).length`

Comment: That's a JavaScript solution, correct?  Mine needs to work outside of JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, it's a javascript solution. You should have something similar to javascript's `match()` in the language you are using. The logic would be the same.